# What does "I don't mind doing something for you?"

Tags: phrases

I asked my teacher to write some recommendation letter for me and he said that "I don’t mind writing a recommendation for you".

I think it means that "I will do that for you" but how good it is?

Does he feel well when he will write it for me?

Does that mean it has no burden for me to do that and I will write it for you?

Comment: Please look up "mind" (verb) up in the dictionary. If that doesn't clear it up then edit what you found into your question.

Comment: Hi Saeed, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to ask questions about English that a fluent speaker would find trivial. To understand which site you should post on, read [this discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell) on Meta. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: @Chappo: Thank you, I will use that website from now on.

Answer (score -1):

“I don't mind” sounds very polite and gentle. It's like the person is saying “It's ok with me/ It does not worry me”